# Reduzir uma string na linguagem C

Tags: c, c++, string

Como faco para reduzir o tamanho de uma *string* em C? No meu programa ela esta implementada da seguinte maneira:

```
char nomeString[] = "nomedoarquivo.txt";
```

Pretendo cortar o ".txt" do final da *string*.

Comment: E qual é o critério? Tem que achar onde tem esse padrão e cortar?Em que contexto está usado? Coloque seu código.

Comment: As strings so teram ".txt" no final delas, eu so queria cortar esses 4 caracteres do final.
char nomeString[] = "nomedoarquivo.txt";
para:
nomeString[] = "nomedoarquivo";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como *strings* em C terminam com um nulo, basta colocar um nulo logo após o texto que deve ficar. Como se saber que o que deve sumir são os últimos 4 caracteres basta colocar o terminador no tamanho da *string* menos 4. Assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char nomeString[] = "nomedoarquivo.txt";
    nomeString[strlen(nomeString) - 4] = '\0';
    printf("%s", nomeString);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/FBkHOd). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sjfavqhm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Cut.c).

Comment: Excelente, muito obrigado!